# Erro ao instalar o pacote RSQLite do R no Windows10

Tags: r

Ao tentar instalar o pacote RSQLite do R no Windows 10 recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro.

```
make: *** [C:/R/R-3.6.1/etc/x64/Makeconf:215: DbDataFrame.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'RSQLite'
* removing 'C:/R/R-3.6.1/library/RSQLite'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘RSQLite’ had non-zero exit status
```

Alguém sabe como resolver esse problema?

Comment: Tem o [Rtools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) instalado? Em Windows precisa de instalar esse conjunto de ferramentas, que são ferramentas padrão em unix/linux.

Answer (score -2):

Tente instalar o este pacote com o comando a seguir:

```
install.packages("ggplot2", dependencies=TRUE)
```

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35674699/12189928)

Comment: Caro amigo, instalei o ggplot2 sem problemas. Esse pacote (ggplot2) não precisa de compilador já o RSQLite necessita. Pelo que já pesquisei o problema deve estar relacionado ao compilador gcc. O que acha? Após instalar o pacote ggplot2, tentei novamente instalar o RSQLite e retornou o mesmo erro.

Comment: Tem razão viajei na questão, não vi que não tinha nada a ver com o ggplot, desculpe. Está instalando pelos binários ?

Comment: Caro Andrey, realmente, resolvi a questão com a ajuda da equipe de suporte do Data Science Academy.  Como comentou em sua reposta, fiz o download do arquivo binário para minha máquina e instalei por ele.  Tudo certo! Muito obrigado!